# Decidability of a given language

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

$L_1=\{ ⟨M⟩ ∣M$ takes at least 2016 steps on some input$\}$

the answer says $L_1$ is recursive.

I am stuck at one point and i am wasting my time on it here for $L_1$ if we are given a set of  to see if it takes at least 2016 steps I can use dovetailing idea and say yes for some inputs here string length doesn't matter right? for the complement of this language for $L_1$ COMPLEMENT, I will have encodings of  that take less than 2016 steps on all inputs how will I check this? if strings of length &n& are taking less than 2016 steps then obviously all the $n+1$ will take less than 2016 to halt is it that way?

then what are the strings which i should check for? please help

Comment: See this very similar question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79255/is-it-decidable-if-a-tm-takes-at-least-2016-steps-on-all-inputs.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus sir I exactly asked the question which they asked this may be very trivial to u  but please make me understand one thing if i check wheter the machine takes less than 2016 steps on all inputs of length atmost 2016 can i declare it takes less than 2016 steps on all the "inputs"

Comment: If you're not sure about something, try to prove it!

Comment: @ Yuval Filmus sir in that case we need not even check for strings till length till 2016 as strings of length n will form prefixes of length n+1 right

Comment: Hint: $L_1 = \{ M \mid |x| < 2016$ and $M(x)$ runs for at least 2016 steps $\} \cup$  $\{ M \mid |x| = 2016, y \in \Sigma^*$ and $M(xy)$ runs for at least 2016 steps $\}$.   The first set is clearly recursive; in order to prove that the second set  is also recursive the "difficult part" is to prove that if $|x|=2016$ then $M(x)$ runs for at least 2016 steps if and only if $\forall y \; M(xy)$ runs for at least 2016 steps ....

Comment: @Vor sir to prove that first we can restrict out domain of "all" to just strings with length <2016 that is <=2015 so if we simulate the turing machine on all the inputs till length ==2015 (because the maximum number of steps we can allow the turing machine to run is 2015 so we dont care about the input beyond 2015 hence if the <M> takes <=2015 steps on all these inputs we can accept it else reject it please correct me ?